# Java hibernate Joined inheritence (id not found)

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, postgresql-9.1, hibernate-annotations

Sorry for my English, it's not my native language and it's allready 2 o'clock, so can't think strait now.
Now i have next problem while using hibernate with Java and PostgreSQL:
I have entity Human and User as follows (with annotation mappings):

```
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
    public class Human implements Serializable{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public static enum Gender{
            Male,
            Female}
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Integer id;
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        private Gender gender;
        @Column
        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        private Date dateOfBirth;
        private String firstName;
        private String middleName;
        private String lastName;
        // getters,setters
    }

    @Entity
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public class User extends Human{
        private static final long serialVersionUID= 1L;
        @Column
        @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
        private Date registrationDate;
        private Boolean activationStatus;
        private String activationCode;
        private String login;
        private String password;
        private String sessionCode;
        private String email;
        private String country;
        private String city;
        private String avatarURL;
        private String description;
        // getters,setters
    }
```

And database structure as follows:

```
human
(
  dateofbirth date NOT NULL,
  firstname text NOT NULL,
  middlename text NOT NULL,
  lastname text NOT NULL,
  id serial NOT NULL,
  gender text,
  CONSTRAINT "Human_id" PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
"user"
(
  login text NOT NULL,
  password text NOT NULL,
  activationcode text NOT NULL,
  activationstatus status NOT NULL,
  avatarurl text NOT NULL,
  city text NOT NULL,
  country text NOT NULL,
  description text NOT NULL,
  registrationdate date NOT NULL,
  email text NOT NULL,
  id integer,
  CONSTRAINT uid PRIMARY KEY (id )
)
```

When I try to run my project (simple unit test) i get next error:

```
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column human0_1_.id does not exist
      Позиция: 778
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1860)
        at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:48)
        at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:42)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3044)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:395)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:375)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:139)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:195)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:878)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:815)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:808)
        at org.tempos.server.modules.users.HumanTest.testGetId(HumanTest.java:31)
...
```

(I cut out tail of log, while it responds on invokin JUnit methods).

Generated query (that fails):

```
select human0_.id as id3_0_, human0_.dateOfBirth as dateOfBi2_3_0_, human0_.firstName as firstName3_0_, human0_.gender as gender3_0_, human0_.lastName as lastName3_0_, human0_.middleName as middleName3_0_, human0_1_.activationCode as activati1_4_0_, human0_1_.activationStatus as activati2_4_0_, human0_1_.avatarURL as avatarURL4_0_, human0_1_.city as city4_0_, human0_1_.country as country4_0_, human0_1_.description as descript6_4_0_, human0_1_.email as email4_0_, human0_1_.login as login4_0_, human0_1_.password as password4_0_, human0_1_.registrationDate as registr10_4_0_, human0_1_.sessionCode as session11_4_0_, case when human0_1_.id is not null then 1 when human0_.id is not null then 0 end as clazz_0_ from Human human0_ left outer join User human0_1_ on human0_.id=human0_1_.id where human0_.id=?
```

As one can see, it tries to JOIN columns on human1_1_.id (originally User.id), but it isn't specified and obtained in SELECT part of query.

What I was tried:

1. Creating @Column private Integer id in class User (got Annotation
   parser exception for overriding primary column for class);
2. Created @Column private Integer hid in class User and set it as
       PrimaryKeyJoinColumn (but i got (should be mapped with
       insert="false" update="false") even if I map it as
       @JoinColumn(insertable=false,updatable=false,referencedColumnName="id"));
3. Created column "hid" and pointed it as PrimaryKeyJoinColumn in
       annotation to column itself, not whole class (got the same error as
       in original, column "human0_1_.id not found);

Anyone, give me some ideas please!

Comment: have you actually checked your db schema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was solved, and mostly thanks to myhaylo.
Original reason for this problem was marked all the time by SQE PMD plugin - "User" is a keyword in SQL-99 syntax. Because of this (looks like), table name was needed to be quoted. It was quoted in PgAdmin query browser, but wasn't in Hibernate generated query, and, indeed, in that case human0_1_.id, which must point to user.id, was pointing to nowhere. 
After changing class and table names to other (like AndhorUser), original database structure posted now in question and classes definitions working well.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to solve the problem. You could already annotated User class with annotation @Table(name="\`User\`"). Grave accent do the trick. For example: http://www.ryanricard.com/blog/2010/10/15/hibernate-mappings-and-oracle-reserved-words/

Answer (score 2):

Your classes should looks like this:
Human

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Inheritance;
import javax.persistence.InheritanceType;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Human implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static enum Gender {
        Male, Female
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Gender gender;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
   .....
}
```

User

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
public class User extends Human {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date registrationDate;

    public Date getRegistrationDate() {
        return registrationDate;
    }

    public void setRegistrationDate(Date registrationDate) {
        this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
    }
    ....
}
```

- Human class should be annotated by @Entity annotation
- Model entity classes should implement Serializable interface

See

1. [Inheritance Type (With Hibernate)](http://blog.v-s-f.co.uk/2010/12/inheritance-type-with-hibernate/).
2. [Inheritance Type JOINED](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/InheritanceTypeJOINED.htm)

Comment: 1) annotated classes as marked above(removed all @ column annotations, added @ PrimaryKeyJoinColumn to table User);
2) added serialVersionUID to both classes and mark Human as 'implements Serializable';
3) marked Human.id as @ GeneratedValue (AFAIK, it doesn't matter as far as i don't insert into table);
4) created field 'id' of type Integer in table User (as shown in suggested link), as PK;
5) all getters and setters allready existed, but wasn't mentioned in above code; BUT still have similar error(human1_1_.id not found)

Comment: I have one more idea. Your's User table contains column with name "hid". Try change it name to "id".

Comment: Already tried and obtained same results. I edited original question to mark all changes made originally from your answer, as they made code simplier, but made no additional errors (on working classes without inheritance). Also, new database structure specified contains column `id` instead of `hid`, and I posted query,generated by Hibernate, and some comment to it.

Comment: After edition, Human class is still not annotated by @Entity annotation. Could You fix it and check is it works?

Comment: It was annotated as @Entity, otherwise it thrown an error "can't find persisted class Human" (or something like this, don't remember exact message), as long as I have a lot of classes with relations to it.